# Multi Processing in Python for loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have written a python code with multi-processing. I did not see much of a performance improvement. I will share the code below. Please help me to understand if there is something missing?

```
if len(aspackets) != len(uepackets):
    sys.exit("Packet number miss match between UE and AS")
else:
    for i in range (1,100):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=packet,args=(i,))
        p.start()
        #p.join()
        E2E(packet(i),i)
        Airinterface(packet(i))
        core(packet(i))
        switch(packet(i))
        inet(packet(i))
        bridge(packet(i))
```

The packet function is as

```
def packet(i):
    return aspackets[i]
```

In my logic, I want to start the processing of multiple packets from a list of 100 packets. The processing of one packet does not affect the other packet. That is, it is okay to start my computation on packet 10 and 33 at the same time. In the normal flow(without multi-processing), I was going sequentiall from 1st to the last packet and had to wait for 45 mins to get the whole results.

I am running this code on Ubuntu machine which is running inside Virtual Box.

Comment: If the code is working fine and you would just like help on improving it, then it is more of a code review question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is no improvement because there is only one process at a time fetching the `packet(i)`. Since this is done over an `iterable` i suggest you try to use [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

Comment: @nutmeg64: So if its an iterable i, multi-processing won work?

Comment: It __will__ work just not in the way you do it. Please read about `Pool` and correct your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def handle_packet(index):
    pac = aspackets[index]
    E2E(pac, index)
    Airinterface(pac)
    core(pac)
    switch(pac)
    inet(pac)
    bridge(pac)

with Pool(processes=10) as p:
    p.map(handle_packet, range(100))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. I can see that the print statements are juggled suggesting that the pools are processing paralelly. But is it possible to output the content again in sequential order?

Comment: Yes. Just write `print(p.map(handle_packet, range(100)))` and make sure that `handle_packet` returns the result you wish to print.

Comment: It is actually printing, but what I want is that the final results be printed from loop 1 to 100 and not just random as per which thread starts first. But if it is not possible, I can just do some text file processing afterwards also.